# Using mutate with dates gives numerical values

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I am using the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages to work with date variables and to create a new date variable, respectively.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
```

Let `df` be my dataframe. I have two variables `date1` and `date2`. I want to create a new variable `date` such that it takes the value of `date1`. If `date1` is missing, value of `date2` is taken instead.

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("24/01/2016",NA,"22/07/2016"),
                 date2 = c("31/01/2016","09/02/2017",NA),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
```

The above command gives:

```
       date1      date2
1 24/01/2016 31/01/2016
2       <NA> 09/02/2017
3 22/07/2016       <NA>
```

I tried the following which I thought can give me the results desired. However, the new `date` variables is in numerics.

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(date1,date2),dmy) %>% 
   mutate(date=ifelse(is.na(date1),date2,date1))

       date1      date2  date
1 2016-01-24 2016-01-31 16824
2       <NA> 2017-02-09 17206
3 2016-07-22       <NA> 17004
```

I want:

```
       date1      date2       date
1 2016-01-24 2016-01-31 2016-01-24
2       <NA> 2017-02-09 2017-02-09
3 2016-07-22       <NA> 2016-07-22
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `dplyr::if_else` instead of `base::ifelse`, which, according to `?if_else`, is type safer,

> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks
>   that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the
>   output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

```
df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(date1,date2),dmy) %>% 
      mutate(date=if_else(is.na(date1),date2,date1))

#       date1      date2       date
#1 2016-01-24 2016-01-31 2016-01-24
#2       <NA> 2017-02-09 2017-02-09
#3 2016-07-22       <NA> 2016-07-22
```

---

Another option is to use `coalesce`, which takes values from `date1` if it is not `NA` otherwise take values from `date2`:

```
df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(date1,date2),dmy) %>% 
      mutate(date = coalesce(date1, date2))

#       date1      date2       date
#1 2016-01-24 2016-01-31 2016-01-24
#2       <NA> 2017-02-09 2017-02-09
#3 2016-07-22       <NA> 2016-07-22
```

---

If you want to keep your original code, just wrap `as.Date` around `ifelse`, since `ifelse` stripped off the class of the result and only keeps the underlying data i.e. *the number of days since 1970-01-01*:

```
df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(date1,date2),dmy) %>% 
      mutate(date=as.Date(ifelse(is.na(date1),date2,date1), origin = "1970-01-01"))
```